# Portaudio: Prevent printing to console in c

Tags: c, visual-studio-2013, portaudio

I am using an external library - **portaudio.h** -  in my project, and one of its functions, `pa_initialize()` prints a lot of informative garbage to the console.

It helps while I debug my project, but it would be problematic when I'll present it.

I couldn't access the library and edit it.

Is there any way of preventing this specific function or a specific section of my code from printing to the console?

I'm writing in C on Visual Studio 2013.

Answer (score 4):

Well, after re-reading the [portaudio documentation](http://portaudio.com/docs/v19-doxydocs/compile_windows.html), I found the solution.

They do provide a predefined way of disabling debug prints when building the project, so I had to rebuilt it, and it worked.

Should have started there...

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

`pa_initialize` may write to `stdout` and `stderr`. You can simply deactivate these streams by closing them. Reactivation is the problem because solutions are not cross-compiler. Following worked for me with MinGW64:

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
    puts("Hello world!");
    fclose(stdout);
    puts("Should not be printed.");
    freopen("CON", "w", stdout);
    puts("Hello again!");
    return 0;
}
```

> Hello world!
>
> Hello again!

For MSVC, following part of `stdio.h` should be interesting for you:

```
_CRTIMP FILE * __cdecl __iob_func(void);

...

#define stdin  (&__iob_func()[0])
#define stdout (&__iob_func()[1])
#define stderr (&__iob_func()[2])
```

Comment: MSVC `fopen` wraps [CreateFile2](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh449422%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), including special filenames for devices (see far down). There's "CON" too.

Answer (score -3):

You can create a function for logging which take a boolean flag which you can set and unset.

eg

```
boolean printOnConsole= false;

void printLog(boolean flag, String data)
{

   if(flag)
          //print yor data on console
}
```

Comment: He says that he "[cannot] access the library and edit it."

Comment: Can I disable printing in my entire project this way?

Comment: Yes you can , set your flag globally

Comment: ...and that helps with the output of an upstream third party library in *which* way, exactly? *The output is not his, it is from libportaudio.*